# React-Native authentication with Azure AD

Tags: azure, react-native, authentication, authorization, azure-active-directory

I am building an app in react-native and need to authenticate to a server via Azure AD. I have tried to google this but surprisingly there is not much content related to this. 
I have found this library 'react-native-azure-ad' but not so much documentation about it. I dont understand how to use it.
My main questions is: Where do I need to place my server's url when using this library, in order to authenticate to it?

Thanks for any suggestions!

**EDIT**:

Here is my code:

```
    import { ReactNativeAD, ADLoginView } from 'react-native-azure-ad'

const CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

    class LandingView2 extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.AzureADContext = {
                client_id: CLIENT_ID,
                // Optional
                redirect_url: 'http://localhost:8080',
                // Optional
                authority_host: 'xxxx',
                // Optional
                tenant: 'common',
                // Optional
                prompt: 'none',
                // Optional
                login_hint: 'user@domain.com',
                // This is required if client_id is a web application id
                // but not recommended doing this way.
                client_secret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                resources: [
                    'https://graph.microsoft.com',
                    'https://outlook.office365.com',
                    // ... more resources
                ]
            }
        }

        render() {

            new ReactNativeAD({
                client_id: CLIENT_ID,
                resources: [
                    'https://outlook.office365.com'
                ]
            })

            return <ADLoginView
                context={ReactNativeAD.getContext(CLIENT_ID)}
                onSuccess={this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this)} />
        }

        onLoginSuccess(credentials) {
            console.log(credentials['https://outlook.office365.com'].access_token)
            // use the access token ..
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two applications in AAD.

- a *native* application for your app
- another application for your server/API

You can then use the clientId or AppID URI of the API as the "resource" for the code shown in the question. All the other parameters are taken from your client app.

If everything is successful, you will get an access token which you can then use as a **bearer token** when calling your API.

```
credentials['https://yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/yourapiname'].access_token
```

Comment: Hi Alex, can you elaborate more in details this example? I am not so much familiar with azure authentication.

Comment: If I create two apps in Azure, what redirect URI should I give to the server app and what to the client app? And what else do I need to provide?